# Can I suppress the errors and warnings in a CSS file, shown by the CSS validator?

Tags: css, validation

I am using several plugins on my site, which have CSS files. When I do a CSS validation on my site, I see the plugins' CSS files consist lots of errors and warnings. Is there a way to make the CSS validator check only the main CSS file of the site, not the plugin ones?

Comment: Validators are bots, they go through every file linked in your page. Go through the validator's options to see if there's any option to exclude CSS files.

Comment: Why would you want to validate only some of the CSS and leave the errors in the rest alone? If you're resigned to using flawed CSS anyway, don't bother validating at all. The other option is to copy the plugins and their CSS files to your own server and then to remove the errors from those as well.